# django: how to pass the selected tag name from template to view

Tags: django, templates, view

I am using a keyword cloud library which only allows the keywords to be in the format of  tags, like:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'infoRetriever:sitelist' (I am not sure) %}" data-weight={{ value }} >{{ key }}</a></li>
```

{{key}} is the keywords extracted from some newspaper articles and there is a dictionary which stores the urls of the articles, and each key corresponds to a list of urls.

Now what I want to do is, when I click on a hyperlink, the page will be redirected to a new page 'sitelist' and display the urls under the key which has been selected.

Does anybody could help me on this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried `"{% url 'infoRetriever:sitelist' tag %}"` yet?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid this is just to represent that the page will be directed to /infoRetriever/sitelist, I don't know how to build the page yet...

Comment: Do you want to build a series of links for each tag? Or you want to pass the key to your page, and then on its template, show the list of tags for that key from the third party app?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I want to build a series links for each tag, when a tag is clicked, the links for that tag will show up.